# How to escape variables in Typoscript setup?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I'm trying to wrap an image with additional HTML elements and parameters, using Typoscript in a Setup Template.

So far, I've managed to wrap elements with HTML, but I'd like to add some parameters as well. The problem occurs, when I try to escape variables in variables - I can't pass UID from one of the parameters.

Below is the sample:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE { 
  tags.img = TEXT
  tags.img {
    current = 1    
    preUserFunc = Netresearch\RteCKEditorImage\Controller\ImageRenderingController->renderImageAttributes
    dataWrap = <a href="{parameters:src}" class="lightbox" title="file:{parameters:data-htmlarea-file-uid}:title" data-lightbox-caption="{file:120:title}" data-lightbox-width="{parameters:width}" data-lightbox-height="{parameters:height}" rel="lightbox-group"> | </a>
}
```

}

The problematic part is here: `title="file:{parameters:data-htmlarea-file-uid}:title"`

I've tried using **{file:{parameters:data-htmlarea-file-uid}:title}**, but it still doesn't work and shows error within rendered element:
[image: error within rendered element]
The only working example is when I hardcode the UID (**{file:120:title}**), but it should be added dynamically, as there are many images.

How can I escape this "double variables"? Or maybe there is another solution to make it work?

==================================================

Here's the full solution of my problem, thanks to [@Jo Hasenau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2333754/jo-hasenau)

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE { 
  tags.img = COA
  tags.img {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      dataWrap = file:{parameters:data-htmlarea-file-uid}:title
      wrap3 = <a href="{parameters:src}" class="lightbox" title="{|}" 
      insertData = 1
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
      dataWrap = file:{parameters:data-htmlarea-file-uid}:description
      wrap3 = data-lightbox-caption="{|}" data-lightbox-width="{parameters:width}" data-lightbox-height="{parameters:height}" rel="lightbox-group">
      insertData = 1
    }
    30 = TEXT
    30 {
      current = 1
      preUserFunc = Netresearch\RteCKEditorImage\Controller\ImageRenderingController->renderImageAttributes
      wrap = |</a>
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dataWrap` and/or `insertData` multiple times either by using the official order of `stdWrap` functions or by squeezing in another "level" of `stdWrap` functions with `stdWrap.functionName`

In this case it's the order of functions combined with a `COA` to separate the original wrap into smaller chunks and some additional braces provided by another wrap.

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE { 
  tags.img = COA
  tags.img {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
      preUserFunc = Netresearch\RteCKEditorImage\Controller\ImageRenderingController->renderImageAttributes
      dataWrap = file:{parameters:data-htmlarea-file-uid}:title
      wrap3 = <a href="{parameters:src}" class="lightbox" title="{|}" data-lightbox-caption="{file:120:title}" data-lightbox-width="{parameters:width}" data-lightbox-height="{parameters:height}" rel="lightbox-group">
      insertData=1
    }
    20 = TEXT
    20.current = 1
    20.wrap = |</a>
  }
}
```

`preUserFunc` will be executed first, then the first `dataWrap` will create the actual variable name, followed by `wrap3` to get the necessary curly braces, finalized by `insertData` to fill in all the other variables together with the generated variable.

The order in this code is just for better readability, but the actual order of function calls within stdWrap is predefined in the PHP code and follows exactly the order of function descriptions in the official docs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html

Comment: This works great with retrieving parameters, but the image to be wrapped is now missing - looks like the part with `20` is not working?

Comment: Ok, I managed to overcome this by adding `preUserFunc` to the last part within `tags.img`. Thanks a lot!